# CSS: How to ignore default hyperlink colors for button class

Tags: html, css

This seems simple enough, but I believe I'm overthinking this so much I'm not able to get this to work.

I have my default hyperlink styles:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
a:visited {
  color: purple;
}
```

And I also have some styling for a button:

```
.button {
  padding: 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid #535353;
  color: #535353;
}
```

Lastly, I have some global classes that are added to elements to customize the font color:

```
.color-green {
  color: green;
}
.color-yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
```

So my problem is dealing with buttons which are hyperlinks, like:

```
<a class="button" href="#">A button</a>
```

I would like any link with class `button` to be `color: #535353;` in it's default state, on hover, and visited. Buttons should always be that color... **unless...**

Unless the button has a color class, such as:

```
<a class="button color-green" href="#">A green button</a>
```

If a button has a color class, the color should change to whichever color class is specified... this includes all states (default, hover, visited).

The problem I am having is just with the `:hover` and `:visited` states of hyperlink buttons. For example, if a button has a color class, the color always changes to red when hovered.

How can I update this so that if a button has a color class, it will be that color in all states?

Keep in mind the color classes are used on all sorts of elements (div, span, p, etc) and also the button classes are used on links, submit buttons, div, etc.

Also please note that a hyperlink my have class `color-yellow`, but I would still want a hyperlink to inherit the default hyperlink hover color. I only want anything with class `button` to ignore the default hyperlink hover and visited colors.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
a:visited {
  color: purple;
}
.button {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid #535353;
  color: #535353;
}
.color-green {
  color: green;
}
.color-yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Normal hyperlink</a>
<a class="color-yellow" href="#">Yellow normal, red hovered</a>
<a class="button" href="#">Default button</a>
<a class="button color-green" href="#">Green color button</a>
```

Comment: Another solution would be to use multiple selectors, aka all `<a>` elements that are also buttons could be styled differently using `a.button{//code}`, `a.button:hover{//code}`, and `a.button:visited{//code}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use **:not** selector

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
a:not(.button):hover {
  color: red;
}
a:not(.button):visited {
  color: purple;
}
```

Comment: I really like this response. Avoids adding additional CSS rules for each state of the other classes, but it has fairly limited support. http://caniuse.com/#search=not()

Comment: @hopkins-matt wrong link, that's for the "selector list argument". `:not()` has good support http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: @hopkins-matt Yes, :not enjoys a pretty good support, event IE9 supports it, which in my opinion pretty decent :)

Comment: @MichaelCoker Oops, my bad! Skimming too fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:not()` in combination with the class attribute wildcard selector to exclude `.color-*` from CSS rules.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
a:not([class*="color-"]):visited {
  color: purple;
}

a:not([class*="color-"]):hover {
  color: red;
}
.button {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid #535353;
  color: #535353;
}
.color-green {
  color: green;
}
.color-yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Normal hyperlink</a>
<a class="button" href="#">Default button</a>
<a class="button color-green" href="#">Green color button</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use-case for `!important`. No need to fiddle with additional markup/rules/selectors.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.button {
  padding: 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid #535353;
  color: #535353 !important;
}

.color-green {
  color: green !important;
}
.color-yellow {
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This link has no class.</a> <br> <br>
<a href="#" class="button">This link has class "button".</a> <br><br>
<a href="#" class="button color-green">This link has classes "button" and "color-green".</a>
```

Comment: I believe OP also wanted persistent `color` on the `.button` class. "I would like any link with class button to be color: #535353; in it's default state, on hover, and visited."

Comment: Thank you for the point-out, I've edited my answer. A simple fix, I've just added the same `!important` to `.button`.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying color class with anchor tag : a.color-green

See below code

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
a:visited {
  color: purple;
}
.button {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid #535353;
  color: #535353;
}
.color-green,
a.color-green {
  color: green;
}
.color-yellow,
a.color-yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Normal hyperlink</a>
<a class="button" href="#">Default button</a>
<a class="button color-green" href="#">Green color button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to point out is that styling these links actually has an order to them. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp). "Your hover MUST go after the visited".

As for the button colors, another thing to point out is that using `.color-green` is not referencing the class you are listing in the link, you write `button color-green` as the class which is not the same thing.

You can set the link style per class. Such as `a.button:hover` so in your case you would have quite a few different ones setup, but what you have at the moment will default to that red for all links.